# WebAudioAPI - getByteFrequencyData return 0 on iOS

Tags: ios, d3.js, safari, web-audio-api

I'm trying to retrieve frequency datas to make a visualisation via D3.js of my audio file and everything works fine on Chrome, Safari, Firefox (desktop) but not in the mobile browsers. The console.log returns 0.

Here's the code:

```
  ...
  var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(1);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);

  svg.selectAll('circle')
     .data(frequencyData)
     .attr('r', function(d) {
        return d;
     })

// This returns 0
```

Is there a problem with that on Safari iOS? I can't figure it out...

Thanks for help!

Comment: Without more of the surrounding code, it's hard to tell.  And does this happen on mobile Chrome?

Comment: Known bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=419446